# Wordpress url_to_postid not working with non-default permalinks

Tags: php, wordpress, url, wordpress-theming

I have a basic Wordpress theme with only one page, that is index.php. I have permalinks set up in the following structure: www.website.com/wp/article-name.

*I will clarify, permalinks work and display the correct content, just script below just doesn't return their id.*

The code below works is supposed to echo the postID that the current URL is referring too and the current URL. It works perfectly for the default permalinks, i.e. www.website.com/wp/?p=1 , but not for my custom permalinks, returns a 0 (fail).  Any ideas why?

```
 <?php  
    $url = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    $postid = url_to_postid( $url );  
    echo $postid; 
    echo $url;
 ?>
```

My .htaccess file currently looks as follows:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /wp/
   RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule . /wp/index.php [L]
  </IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Help is very much appreciated.

Comment: did you check your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: What should I be looking for in the .htaccess file? I'll post contents up now.

Comment: I'm editing the files locally and uploading to the live server (remote  shared hosting with cpanel).

Comment: give me development url please

Comment: did you try to use [get_page_by_path()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_path) or [get_page_by_title()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_title)

Comment: In my case `HTTP_HOST` didn't include the protocol `http://` and after I appended that it worked. So check and append if missing.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using using `url_to_postid( $url )`, try:

```
$page = get_page_by_path($slug_of_url);
echo $page->ID ;
```

;) It always works for me.

Comment: This only works for pages by default. Check the documentation for how to use it for other post type:  https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_path